# How can I check the latency of Mailgun emails?

Tags: mailgun

Some of my emails are taking a long time to be sent, and I want to know exactly how long. How can I view the time delta between mail-request and mail-sent in the Mailgun interface?

Answer (score 1):

The Mailgun API has an [events](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#events) option that can be queried for `delivered`:

```
Mailgun sent the email and it was accepted by the recipient email server.
```

You can access Events through a few interfaces:

- Webhooks (we POST data to your URL).
- The Events API (you GET data through the API).
- The Logs Tab of the Control Panel (GUI).